# Число комбинаций при которых хотя бы одна цифра на своем месте

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Есть 5 позиций (первая-пятая). Есть 5 цифр 1-5. Как посчитать число комбинаций, при которых хотя бы одна цифра будет на своей позиции (1 в первой или 5 в пятой, или 12345 и тд). Для частного случая посчитать могу, а формулу в общем виде вывести не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Все перестановки = N!
Все беспорядки(!n) = Сумма[k=0 -> N]((-1)^k N!/k!)
Перестановки, содержащие хотя бы одну неподвижную точку = N! - !n
```

Для N = 5:

```
!n = N! - N!/1 + N!/2! - N!/3! + N!/4! - N!/5! 
   = N!(1/2 - 1/6 + 1/24 - 1/120)
N! - !n = N!(1 - 1/2 + 1/6 - 1/24 + 1/120)
        = 120(...) = 120 - 60 + 20 - 5 + 1 = 76
```

---

[Беспорядки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Comment: Благодарю. Из знаний была только простейшая комбинаторика, из 7 класса, и в ней такого не было. Если кому интересно, статья на вики называется `Беспорядок (перестановка)`.